# Find maximum value $|z_1+z_2| + |z_1-z_2|$, with $|z_1|=|z_2|=1$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ be two complex numbers such that $|z_1|=|z_2|=1$. Then find the max value of
$$|z_1+z_2| + |z_1-z_2|$$

In my opinion the answer should be 4, because the maximum values of both terms is 2. The given answer is $2\sqrt 2$, though. I just want to verify whether I am making a mistake or the given answer is wrong.

Comment: They aren't independent. The expression is equivalent to $2|sin(x/2)+cos(x/2)|$ whose max value is 2root(2) where x is the angle between z1,z2 position vectors

Comment: Geomtrically, we are looking for 2 points on the unit circle whose sum of distances to O is maximized. Due to symmetry (that needs a little more rigor) one can observe that points on either $y=x$ and $y=-x$ intersecting with the unit circle works. This argument also works if you want to find the minimum instead of maximum. Instead of the given lines, you need two other lines. I am not posting as a worked out answer, because given answers are complete in my view. But there is more than one way to skin a cat...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometrically, $z_1$ and $z_2$ are on a unit circle. Assume they form a angle $2\theta$, then
$$|z_1+z_2| + |z_1-z_2|=2 \sin\theta +2\cos\theta=2\sqrt2\sin(\theta+\frac\pi4)\le 2\sqrt2
$$
with the max value at the right angle subtended by $z_1$ and $z_2$ to the center.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot take the maximum value as $4$ because the terms are not independent(try to find when the equality occurs (it doesnt!)).

As ${(a+b)}^2\le 2(a^2+b^2)\iff {(a-b)}^2\ge 0$ $${(|z_1+z_2|+|z_1-z_2|)}^2\le 2(|z_1+z_2|^2+|z_1-z_2|^2)=8$$ $$\Rightarrow |z_1+z_2|+|z_1-z_2|\le 2\sqrt{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $f,g\colon[-1,1]\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ are defined by $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$, then $\max f=\max g=1$, but $\max(f+g)=1$ too, not $2$.

The answer that you were given is correct. let $\omega=\frac wz$ and take $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ such that $e^{i\alpha}=\frac wz$. Then\begin{align}|z+w|+|z-w|&=\left|1+\frac wz\right|+\left|1-\frac wz\right|\text{ (because $|z|=1$)}\\&=|1+\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha|+|1-\cos\alpha-i\sin\alpha|\\&=\sqrt{2+2\cos\alpha}+\sqrt{2-2\cos\alpha}\\&=2\left|\cos\frac\alpha2\right|+2\left|\sin\frac\alpha2\right|\\&\leqslant2\sqrt2.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You are asked to find the maximum of the sum of the lengths of diagonals $h+d$ of a rhombus of side $a=1$.

Where $\begin{cases}z_1\equiv\vec{AB} && z_1+z_2\equiv\vec{AC}\\z_2\equiv\vec{BC}&& z_1-z_2\equiv\vec{DB}\end{cases}$

Since $(h+d)^2=h^2+d^2+2dh=4a^2+4S=4(S+1)$

Then $h+d=2\sqrt{S+1}$ is maximal when the area is maximal.

This happens when the rhombus is a square, i.e. when $S=\sin(\alpha)=1\iff \alpha=\frac{\pi}2$

In this case $h+d=2\sqrt{1+1}=2\sqrt{2}$

Comment: You can also look at this nice animation https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1562839/399263