# Can I prove Pythagoras Theorem by concatenating four right triangles?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, solution-verification

I was considering ways to visually prove Pythagoras' Theorem.

I was reasoning if I could concatenate the same right triangle four times, as if it was reflected from both axis.

[image]

Why can't I just calculate the area of this diamond to know *c*?

What am I doing wrong? Why does it make no sense?
Please, excuse me if I'm doing an obvious mistake or wrong assumption.

Thanks.

Comment: If you imagine $a$ to be really small, you can see that the area is almost zero.  If $a$ is about equal to $b$, then the area is relatively large, but $c$ is the same in both cases.  The point here is that the area doesn't determine $c$.

Comment: You can just as easily rearrange those four triangles to construct a rectangle of area $4ab$. That tells you nothing about $c$.

Comment: Here there is something to visually understand it better https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1562759/436114. I will learn more about rhombus properties.

Comment: @B.Goddard, Thanks for your answer. Is there a particular resource you would recommend to continue exploring these geometry basics that also kind of brings together Pythagoras theorem?

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

The shape you have drawn is a rhombus. The area of a rhombus is defined to be $\frac{pq}2$ where $p$ and $q$ are the lengths of both the diagonals.

Therefore, the area of the shape you have drawn is calculated by considering the fact that $p=2b$ and $q=2a$. And so the area would be $\frac{(2a)(2b)}2=2ab$.

We can of course verify this by calculating the area of one of the right angle triangles and then multiplying by $4$. The area of one triangle is $\frac{ab}2$ and so multiplied by $4$ gives us the same answer for the total area as $2ab$.

However, this doesn’t help us to find $c$, since the formula for the area is independent of $c$

*Note: c is not independent of the area. We just need Pythagoras’ Theorem to show that this is the case. Since we are trying to proof Pythagoras’ Theorem, we must use a formula in terms of a and b which make the area independent of c*.

So you haven’t written anything explicitly wrong. The only problem is that, this doesn’t prove Pythagoras’ theorem.

Expanding upon something correctly stated in the comments, we also have the problem of the fact that we are stating the formula for the area of a rhombus without any explicit proof. And so this is also a consideration we need to make before even making an attempt to use the formula for a proof.

Comment: You can equate $2ab$ with some other formula (that involves $c$) for the area of one of the triangles, and derive the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't quite understand why c is independent of the area. I mean, it seems strange at first glance, also considering that a rhombus has similar characterstics to a square.

Comment: Yes, I acknowledge this at the end of my response. The problem is that we must first derive this formulae before going on to produce a proof. We cannot just state the formulae to prove another formula when they are require Pythagoras’ Theorem to be true in the first place @Alex

Comment: @Aleix it is not very strange considering that the square is a (very) important special case of the rhobus, so needing $c$ in the case of a square kinda makes sense.

Comment: Your intuition is correct. The area is determined by a and b (which are linked by Pythagoras’ Theorem) and so c isn’t independent of the area in practice. However, because we cannot assume Pythagoras’ Theorem (since we are looking for a proof), we cannot state that the area is dependent on c without having a formula to show that this is the case @Aleix

Comment: Is there a particular resource you recommend to continue exploring geometry? What  things are assumed, how to derive and prove its properties (sort of for inexperienced people)?

Comment: In terms of proof writing, the best approach to take is to look up the proofs of certain properties. For example, when you came up with this idea, a good idea would be to look up “proof of the area of a rhombus”, which would have shown you that we need Pythagoras’ Theorem in the first place before we can use this formula @Aleix

Comment: Regarding resources,  there is a huge amount of research on geometry and so it’s difficult to recommend one in particular. If you are looking for a very rigorous, undergraduate level geometry book then I can make some recommendations. If you are looking for something a bit more basic, then there are some great playlists on youtube depending on your focus. The resources very much depend on whether or not you’re more interested in proofs, or learning about properties in order to solve problems @Aleix

Comment: I would be more interested in proofs, at a basic level @FD_bfa.